# How can I save user's phone number after he shared his contact

Tags: c#, request, bots, contacts, telegram

this is my telegram bot keyboardbuttons:

```
var keyboard = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup(new[]
            {
                new [] // first row
                {
                    **new KeyboardButton("ارسال شماره تماس")
                     {
                        RequestContact = true
                     }** 
                },
                new [] // last row
                {
                    new KeyboardButton("درباره ما"),
                    new KeyboardButton("ارتباط با ما"),  
                }

            });
```

How can I save user's phone number after he shared his contact?
(I want to get his phone number and check it with phone numbers in my database)

I try this, but it doesn't work (The condition is not true):

```
if (message.Type == MessageType.ContactMessage)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("aaaa");
            string ph = message.Contact.PhoneNumber;
            await Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(message.Chat.Id, ph, replyMarkup: keyboard);
        }
```

Comment: Nobody could help me????? pllllleeeeaaase, I need help.

Answer (score 0):

MrRoundRobin says: If the user presses the custom keyboard button with RequestContact = true you will receive an update with Update.Type == MessageUpdate and the contact information in Update.Message.Contact.

https://github.com/MrRoundRobin/telegram.bot/issues/198

I fix this problem by this part of code:

```
  static async Task GetContactPhoneNumber()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var Updates = await Bot.GetUpdates();

            foreach (var update in Updates)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("aaaa");
                if (update.Type == UpdateType.MessageUpdate)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("bbb");
                    var cc = update.Message.Contact.PhoneNumber;
                    //string ph = message.Contact.PhoneNumber;
                    await Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(update.Message.Chat.Id, cc);

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can't access to phone number! telegram bot doesn't return phone number of user. for sent message to all of your users you most using chat-id.

Comment: Thanks. But I want save phone number after that user share it with bot in private chat. It shoud be passible!!

Comment: not possible. you can read this: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#user

Comment: But phone number in https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#contact where used?
(I put request_contact button in bot, when user press that, his contact share in bot)